# Rendr add custom header to fetch request (such as basic auth)

Tags: rendr

I'm building a Rendr app and I'd like to populate my user model by making a request to my API service's `/login` endpoint. That endpoint simply expects a basic auth header.

I see Rendr has an [option to allow custom headers](https://github.com/rendrjs/rendr/pull/310) but the problem is the header is only added from the client to the Rendr node.js server. When the API proxy intercepts my requests and makes a call to `http://my-api.com/login` the basic auth header is not carried through to this request. I'm assuming the apiProxy ignores these headers- it has no way to know what header is custom.

How can I define a custom header client side and ensure the header is added to an API request?

```
this.app.fetcher.fetch({
    user: {
        model: 'User',
        params: {}
    }}, {
     headers': {
        "Authorization": "Basic abcdefg12345678"
    }
   }, function(err, user){

});
```

This example only adds a header from client -> Rendr node server, not NOT from Rendr node server --> my API service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together an npm module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rendr-api-proxy-optionable that should do what you need.

It allows pass throughs of request and response headers at the api proxy level.

Hope that helps!